# Old cartoon where a boy, girl and whale go on adventures fighting the evil guys trying to collect plates-rock pieces

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This is an old cartoon that is set on an island and presents a boy with sand hair who trained with his teacher. He goes on travels with a whale and a girl I think looking for sacred plates-rock pieces that I think are 24. They also fight evil guys that are trying to take the plates for evil.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you watch this? I've also edited to try and make this clearer, if I have changed the meaning of any of the sentences feel free to change my wording.

Comment: @user112289 As well as looking through the guide suggested by TheLethalCarrot, I think your question could be helped by clearing up some of story specific details you've already mentioned. What did the teacher 'train' the boy in? What are plates-rock? How did the pair travel with the whale? e.g. in the whale, on the whale, on a boat next to the whale, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It might be the series which is called *Moby Dick and the Secret of Mu* (2005). Which is a French TV series originally called *[Moby Dick et le Secret de Mu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Dick_et_le_Secret_de_Mu)*.

[image: DVD front cover]

> Romy, un garçon intrépide de 12 ans, part à la recherche des 24 tablettes de Mu qui lui dévoileront le secret tant oublié de la cité disparue sous le grand cataclysme. En compagnie de ses amis Zû et Satya, il devra voyager d'un coin à l'autre du globe sous les conseils de Kamal. Cependant il sera poursuivi par le terrible Capitaine Achab et ses deux acolytes, Flask et Stubb sur leur navire, le Péquod... De surcroit, Moby Dick, la baleine blanche, pire cauchemar d'Achab, sera de la partie. Le cétacé prêtera main-forte à nos trois héros dans leur quête du passé, mais cela sera-t-il suffisant face aux nombreuses péripéties que rencontrera Romy ?!

(translation to English)

> Romy, a fearless boy of 12 years, goes in search of the 24 tablets of Mu, which will unveil to him the forgotten secret of the city which disappeared during the great cataclysm. Along with his friends Zû and Satya, he will have to travel from one corner of the globe to the other under Kamal's guidance. However he will be pursued by the terrible Captain Ahab and his two acolytes, Flask and Stubb, on their ship, the Pequod... In addition, Moby Dick, the white whale, worst nightmare of Ahab, will be in the mix. The cetacean will lend a hand to our three heroes in their quest for the past, but will it be enough in the face of the many trials that Romy will encounter?

Comment: Could you [edit] this to further expand on how it matches the OP’s description?